# AES crypt function with C# and decrypt using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, aes

I'm trying to code a C# crypt function that I can decrypt with JavaScript,
is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746347/simple-string-encryption-in-net-and-javascript

Comment: A quick Google come up with this: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: Yes, but if you're trying to not use SSL, please stop and use SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applications that require higher security I usually encode and decode using C#, and use $.ajax in JS, but there is an easy way using JS to decode  a pre-encrypted string .

You can use Base64String...

C# :

```
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
```

JS :

```
function decode(str) {
  var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
  var output = "";
  var chr1, chr2, chr3;
  var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
  var i = 0;

  do {
     enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(str.charAt(i++));
     enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(str.charAt(i++));
     enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(str.charAt(i++));
     enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(str.charAt(i++));

     chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
     chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
     chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

     output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

     if (enc3 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
     }
     if (enc4 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
     }
   } while (i < str.length);

  return output;
}
```

Comment: I know some may not agree with me, but I believe that having a client side script inherently conflict with aes encryption standards. This is one of the reasons I only encrypt / decrypt server side, and use json calls to communicate. That way I can also use sessions, cookies, etc... and make sure the encryption is very strong, rather than using C#/ JS encryption.

Comment: That's [tag:encoding], not [tag:encryption].

Comment: had you bothered reading my comments, and notes you'd notice that I call it encoding and not encrypting. in my comment i was making a case for encrypting, and made clear that you cannot do it on the client side, and when I do need something encrypted I do it exclusively on the server side !